# Screenshot with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a map from 2gis.com on my site. And you need to make a screen of this block with a map on js, decided to use the html2canvas library and when the script does it it turns out a white block. Please tell me how can I fix it?

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#map"), {

}).then(canvas => {
    $('#test-img').append(canvas);
});
```

Comment: What do you want achieve again? it turns out like what?

Comment: turns white block, need a map

Comment: Could you please show it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or snippets so we can clearly know this issue

Comment: There are no errors, when processing the code, this answer is given, but a map is needed  [Screenshots](http://prntscr.com/lcie73)